# Should we merge [object-oriented-perl] and [perl-oo] tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

These two tags seem to refer to the same thing. Could you merge them?

Description of [object-oriented-perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-perl):

```
Object-Oriented Programming in Perl
```

Description of [perl-oo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-oo):

```
refers to object-oriented programming in Perl
```

Comment: Those definitely should be merged, but it's worth noting that there are about 6X as many questions that just have both tags [perl and oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop+perl). Maybe we should just retag all of them to that?

Comment: @BilltheLizard I don't know what the best practice is, but your suggestion makes sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've performed the merge, such that [object-oriented-perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-perl) ← [perl-oo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl-oo).

However, I agree with Bill the Lizard: there is no need for a "combined" [object-oriented-perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object-oriented-perl) tag. It doesn't refer to a specific library as far as I can tell, so these questions would be better served by the separate tags [perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/perl) and [oop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oop).

There is no automated tool to do that. Community members will have to do this by retagging the questions. You retag by editing, and remember that when editing, you're supposed to fix ***all*** of the apparent problems with the post, including spelling/grammar, formatting, bad titles, and other invalid/missing tags. It's also a good time to flag/vote off-topic or inappropriate questions as such.

It's right at 50 questions with the tag now, so pretty manageable. I'm going to declare this as something that any interested party can take up and work on as desired, without the need to file a formal [burnination request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).